# Azure Data lake packages

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

We have tried creation of packages in Azure data lake but we aren't able to declare the table valued function & Procedures ,Views in Azure data lake package. 
If you can provide the code it will be very useful to us.

Comment: This is too broad.  What code have you tried?  Do you get a specific error?  The main documentation page for U-SQL Packages is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt808778.aspx) and it is quite clear that DDL is not allowed inside a package.

Comment: Thanks bob. I am aware that we can't use the DDL statements but we want to declare as part of migration from cosmos to ADL. earlier in cosmos we are using modules so we would like to know is there any replacement DDL statement to use in Packages.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use DDL in packages. You just write a script that creates your objects once in the meta data service. Then you just need to reference them in later scripts.

That's the benefit of a meta data system: You do not have to create the objects every time anew.

Comment: Thanks Michael. If you don't mind can you please share the sample scripts to invoke function or procedures inside u sql package.

Comment: There are several samples on the U-SQL GitHub site in the Examples directory that you can reach via http://usql.io. I would look at the tweetanalysis and AmbulanceDemos. Also the documentation contains examples.